# Ubuntu for Android, Ubuntu for Devices, LinuxonAndroid project for Ubuntu on ARMv7 machine?

Tags: system-installation, devices, chroot, arm, ubuntu-for-android

I've looked around but can't find any solid solutions or help on this topic.
I recently ordered a machine with an ARMv7 CPU (Cortex A-9, <= 1.6GHz, quad core). The machine also has a Mali-400 quad-core GPU @ 533, supposedly, along with 2GB RAM and 8GB ROM, several USB ports -- one host (single port hub?).

I recently discovered "Ubuntu for Android" (http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android), as well as Ubuntu for Devices (http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/). The latter appears to be more of a mobile experience, whereas I'm hoping for a 'desktop' experience.

Ubuntu for Android claims to run alongside Android and given that my coming machine is a quad-core ARMv7 CPU with Android 4.1.1 loaded, this interests me greatly and I believe it to be possible, however I cannot find appropriately concise documentation. If all I get here is a point in the right direction, I'll be eternally grateful.
I do know that there are similar machines that come with Ubuntu preloaded.

Finally, in the past, I've run Debian in a chroot on my old 800MHz phone with something like 190MB RAM. It was an ARMv6, therefor there is no Ubuntu build for it so I have yet to try it out but Debian worked fine*, I've already got a 12.04 image ready for my ARMv7 when it gets here, but I will likely need to first obtain access to the root user, although the app GNURoot looks promising to avoid this. I suspect the same will apply for installing Ubuntu, unless it involves a straight ROM flash.. which I hope not because I doubt anyone has worked on one for this machine.. regardless, I seek council.

Edit for clarity:
I'm looking to know the most cohesive way to achieve an Ubuntu experience on this device. If I have to, I will attempt via the chroot method but if anyone can help me to get *Devices or *Android happening, that will be my goal.
/edit

Here's hopin' the knowledge springs forth*

Comment: ubuntu for android doesn’t exist in the "wild" they just developed it and are trying to sell it to phone makers, also What Machine? there are many small android boards that will run a plain desktop of Ubuntu, and you might want to split the second part into a separate question.

Comment: Ok, it looked as if that was the case for the Android project. Thanks for the info, there. The machine is generic, which is why I threw in the CPU and GPU but it's an RK3188 chipset, here is a link to a product page: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/New-2014-made-in-China-Quad_1803353910.html
Also, I've edited the OP to clarify that I'm looking for the best method to obtain Ubuntu on the device.